# I can't find the value of the “k” smallest integer in "n" amount of integers in a list

Tags: python

```
n = input('print n：')
k = input('print k')
a = input('print'+str(n)+'numbers：')
s = str(a)
Lst = s.split()
map_object = map(int, Lst)
lst = list(map_object)
```

I have the rest done, and I don't know how to find and print the k smallest integer.

inputs:

10(n) 3(k)

1 3 3 7 2 5 1 2 4 6(n amount of numbers)

outputs:

3

Comment: That's a matrix, and this is a list. unfortunately, I have not learned matrixes yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can have duplicate numbers, so first we are getting rid of them by using `set()`:

```
no_duplicates = set(lst)
```

Then we sort it, which will return us sorted list:

```
sorted_list = sorted(no_duplicates)
```

Then we get your desired number (you haven't converted `k` to int, so we will do it here):

```
kth_smallest = sorted_list[int(k)-1]
```

Comment: When i added the codes below my original codes, it said unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'str' and 'int' on line 15

Comment: just write `print(kth_smallest)`

Comment: Nope. Still said  unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'str' and 'int' on line 15.

Comment: wait! i added int() to k then it worked!

Comment: huh, okay, my mistake, I will edit answer